# How can I target a specific list item that has the same class as all other list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so my script allows me to input text in a textarea element and add it to a li element within an ordered list with the id "Glist". Not only is text added to each li I add to the ordered list, but the additional things below are added as well and they all just display additional images using CSS. One of the classes, "Selimg" displays a sprite image of a button that says "select". Now each li element I add to my ol has all of the elements below as well as the classes. So each li element will have a div with a "Selimg" class that displays an image of a button that says select for example. When I click this div with the class Selimg, a new class named "Selected" will be added to the div which will change the background color of the li to indicate that it has been selected. The problem is, I want to only add the "Selected" class to the div with the Selimg class that I've clicked, not all li elements with "Selimg" classes. How can I do that with an onclick event handler or any other way using js or jquery? Here's the html:

```
<ol id="GList">
<li class="MyList">
<p class="bulletp"></p>
<!--This Selimg class displays an image of a button that says select-->
<div class="Selimg"></div>
<!--When a user presses this select button, I want to append a class only to the   specific li element the user has pressed the select button on. -->
<div class="edit1"></div>
<div class="Del"></div>
<div class="progress"></div>
<div class="ShowMore"></div>
<div class="CheckedGoal"></div>
<div class="PCompetePercent"></div>
<div class="ShowMoreBlock"></div>
<div class="goalTxt"></div>
</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the click of the button, you can use `.closest()` to find the ancestor `li` element

```
$('.Selimg').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('someclasss')
    //or $(this).parent().addClass('someclasss') since the li is the parent of the button
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fSMDv/)

Comment: Ah, true. Thanks. But now the issue is that they can all be selected. How could I make it so once I select another li item, all other li elements aren't selected. I think I know of a way but I believe there's a more simpler solution I'm not thinking of. Sorry i did not include this in my post. i hadn't thought of it until I tried your fiddle.